# Find the Maclaurin series and state where it is valid.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}-\frac{z}{z-3}$ would I be right in saying that it's Maclaurin series for $|z|<1$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n*z^n +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}$ ?

And would $f^{10}(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Now  $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}-\frac{z}{z-3}$

$ = 1+(-z)+(-z)^2+(-z)^3+.... $ $ - \frac{z-3+3}{z-3} $

$ = 1+(-z)+(-z)^2+(-z)^3+.... -1 + \frac{1}{\frac{z}{3}  -1} $

$ = 1+(-z)+(-z)^2+(-z)^3+.... -1 - \frac{1}{1 -\frac{z}{3}  } $

$ = 1+(-z)+(-z)^2+(-z)^3+.... -1 - (1 + \frac{z}{3} + \frac{z^2}{3^2} +...) $

You can work out the rest.

Comment: I'm giving this a down vote because I only wanted to know if what I had was correct.

Comment: I would like to know why I got a negative vote for this? Is there something that I should be aware of? I wanted to point out that the  Maclaurin series was not worked out correctly.

Comment: Ok. You can get it right then!

Comment: I need a closed form using summation since I need the 10th derivative.

Comment: $ \frac{f^{10}(0)}{10!}$ = Coefficient of the term $z^{10} $?

Comment: Closed form should not be difficult. There was just a computational mistake in the series that you obtained. Proceed similarly. You should be able to get it.